# Sitecore: How to handle uploading of broken Images in Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am using following code to upload images in Sitecore Media Library, from stream `System.IO.Stream`.

```
 var creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
             creator.CreateFromStream(stream, e.UploadedFile.SourceName, options);
```

**Few details:**

`e.UploadedFile.SourceName:` is the path for the uploaded file

```
 var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
            {
                FileBased = false,
                KeepExisting = true,
                Versioned = true,
                Destination = // A 'Media Folder' item in media library ,
                Database = Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
                AlternateText = "some text"
            };
```

As long as I am uploading images the above code works fine. I tried to upload a broken image, then I got the exception:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
```

**on this line**:  `creator.CreateFromStream(stream, e.UploadedFile.SourceName, options);`

I tried to handle it with Try, Catch as follows but its not working.

```
try
   {
   var creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
   MediaItem mediaItem = creator.CreateFromStream(stream, e.UploadedFile.SourceName, options);

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

    throw new ApplicationException("Something wrong happened in the calculation module :", ex);

   }
```

Comment: What exactly is a broken image?

Comment: e.g. Saved a text file with extension 'jpg' and tried to upload. Or Image not in proper format.

Comment: What do you want to happen when an image is broken?

Comment: I just want to show a message that image is broken or  image cannot be uploaded.